# Relationship between SVM normal vector w and hyperplane margin 2/||w||

Tags: geometry, svm

We're studying Support Vector machines and the text states that the margin between closest points is equal to 2 over the norm of the normal vector w, but I can't understand how. I've Googled it and seen a bunch of sites say that it is, but none of them explain to me why the margin is inversely proportional to the magnitude of the hyperplane's normal vector. Shouldn't it be the opposite? I'm probably misunderstanding something fundamental but I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was thinking about the SVM margin backwards, and it makes more sense when you consider that the largest margin would not only be the largest possible space between the hyperplane and the two classes, but also the smallest. This is true because as one side gets larger when the line moves, the other side gets smaller. This is why the inverse property holds.